# jQuery get the document width and height excluding horizontal/vertical scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

I have a piece of jQuery on my site that displays an overlay the full width and height of the window. I have an issue in that if the overlay is closed (as there is an option to close it) I lose the vertical scroll bar from my window. Is there a way to specify the width and height **excluding** any horizontal or vertical scrollbars?

This is my code below, the jQuery will run as soon as the page loads.

```
    <div id="screen"></div>

        $('#screen').css({ "display": "block", 
                            opacity  : 0.7,
                            "width"  : $(document).width(),
                            "height" : $(document).height()
                            });
        $('body').css({ "overflow" : "hidden" });
```

Comment: `overflow:hidden` is causing the scrollbars to hide. Just don't set that property, or restore its initial value on close.

Comment: try using overflow :auto

Comment: @Ajaybeni Happy to accept your comment as the answer, or either of these really, if you want to submit it. Thanks - that worked!

Comment: @RobW Same for yourself, Rob.

Comment: @Ajaybeni Go ahead, I said what's wrong with it, you offered the solution :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
$('#screen').css({ "display": "block", 
                    opacity  : 0.7,
                    "width"  : $(document).width(),
                    "height" : $(document).height()
                    });
$('body').css({ "overflow" : "auto" });
```